# react-Native Change color on selected item in flatlist

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have a flat list that renders several buttons, I want to mark the selected button inside esee flat list, I tried a lot of things but in all of them the flat list mark all the items once I select one, besides that, it does not update until i Update something in the component and save the changes, then it does hot reloading and this is how the marked items are displayed

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       pressStatus: false,
    };

    _onShowUnderlay(){
       this.setState({ pressStatus: true });
    }

    render() {
       return (
          <FlatList
                    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                    data={this.state.ninosPicker}
                    renderItem={({item}) => (
                       <View style={styles.hijos}>
                          <TouchableHighlight
                             activeOpacity={1}
                             underlayColor="#3fa9f5"
                             onShowUnderlay={this._onShowUnderlay.bind(this)}
                             style={this.state.pressStatus ? styles.buttonPress : styles.botonsito }
                             onPress={() => this.setHijo(item.grado, item.grupo)}>
                                 <Text style={this.state.pressStatus ? styles.welcomePress : styles.titBtnGyG }>{item.name}</Text>
                           </TouchableHighlight>
                           <TouchableHighlight
                              activeOpacity={1}
                              underlayColor="#3fa9f5"
                              style={this.state.pressStatus ? styles.gradosPress : styles.grados }>
                                  <Text style={this.state.pressStatus ? styles.welcomePress : styles.titBtnGyG }>{item.grado}</Text>
                           </TouchableHighlight>
                           <TouchableHighlight
                               activeOpacity={1}
                               underlayColor="#3fa9f5"
                               style={this.state.pressStatus ? styles.grupoPress : styles.grupo }>
                                   <Text style={this.state.pressStatus ? styles.welcomePress : styles.titBtnGyG }>{item.grupo}</Text>
                           </TouchableHighlight>
                       </View>
                      )}/>
```

Comment: Hi David, were you able to fix the issue? how did you go about it? Any help plz?

Answer (score 1):

You have to take into account that in the coding you are placing a unique state, in this case this.state.pressStatus, what you need is to have in the arrangement in each object a property pressStatus, at the time of executing the action of the button you have to change the state of that button

Comment: Might you provide an example to make your answer easier to understand?