# react-native How to change an item's style rendered in FlatList after "touch" it?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to change item's style such as color or fontSize in FlatList, I checked some questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53616736/change-the-style-of-only-onpressed-item-of-flatlist) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601413/react-native-change-color-on-selected-item-in-flatlist) , but they don't work in my code. If I use loop instead of FlatList I can successfully change item's style..

Here is my code

```
let jobCategory= [
    {
        "id": "a",
        "name": "1",
    },
    {
        "id": "b",
        "name": "2",
    },
    {
        "id": "c",
        "name": "3",
    },
    {
        "id": "d",
        "name": "4",
    },
    {
        "id": "e",
        "name": "5",
    },
    {
        "id": "f",
        "name": "6",
    },
]


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    categoryUnselectedStyle: {
        paddingTop: pxToDp(25),
        paddingBottom: pxToDp(25),
        paddingRight: pxToDp(30),
        paddingLeft: pxToDp(30),
        backgroundColor: '#f4f6f7',
    },
    categoryselectedStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    categoryTextUnselectedStyle: {
        color: '#666666',
        fontSize: pxToDp(28)
    },
    categoryTextselectedStyle: {
        color: 'lightblue',
        fontSize: pxToDp(40),
    },
});


const JobExpectPage = (props) => { 
    const [categorySelected, setCategorySelected] = useState("")


        const renderJobCategory = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                key={item.id}
                onPress={() => setCategorySelected(item.id)}
                style={[styles.categoryUnselectedStyle, categorySelected == item.id && styles.categoryselectedStyle]}
            >
                <View>
                    <Text style={[styles.categoryTextUnselectedStyle, categorySelected == item.id && styles.categoryTextselectedStyle]}> {item.name}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }




    return (
        <View> 
            <FlatList 
                data={jobCategory}
                renderItem={renderJobCategory}

        </View>

    )
}
```

I hope after I press the item ,  it's style would be changed. I have already succeed without FlatList, how could I make it with FlatList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the flatlist is not rerendering as the `array jobCategory` is always the same.

You must add the property extraData to the flatlist and pass the categorySelected hook, so the flatlist then knows that when categorySelected changes, it has to rerender, do it as follows:

```
 return (
        <View> 
            <FlatList 
                data={jobCategory}
                renderItem={renderJobCategory}
                extraData={categorySelected}
        </View>

    )
```

> By passing extraData={categorySelected to FlatList we make sure
>   FlatList itself will re-render when the categorySelected changes.
>   Without setting this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to
>   re-render any items because it is also a PureComponent and the prop
>   comparison will not show any changes.

Comment: But the renderJobCategory function is changed after each call to setCategorySelected. So it should work even without the extraData field.